# A polynomial with the property $P(1)=1$ can't have three distinct roots?

Tags: polynomials

For polynomial $P$ with whole-number coefficients, it is given that $P(1)=1$. Prove that this polynomial doesn't have three distinct whole-number roots.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are they integer roots, complex roots or what? You need to specify.

Comment: Question. What can you conclude from $a $ is a root of $P$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that mr.pigeon.

Comment: If $a$ is a root of $P$, then $x-a$ divides $P(x)$. Try using this.

Comment: If $n$ is a root then you can write $P(x) = (x-n) Q(x)$ where $Q$ also has integer coefficients. Rinse & repeat twice. Now evaluate the result at $x=1$ and use properties of integers.

Comment: Key to understand is why it was asked for whole numbers, and not for more popular natural numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume there are three distinct roots, $a,b,c$.

$$P(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)Q(x)$$

$$P(1) = (1-a)(1-b)(1-c)Q(1) = 1$$

This implies $(1-a), (1-b), (1-c) \in \{-1,1\}$, which implies at most two distinct roots.

Comment: Why does $Q$ have to be an integer then? That is what a proper proof of this have to demonstrate.

Comment: That's what happens when you have a polynomial with integer coefficients is divided by a linear expression of $x-r$ where $r$ is a root. You wind up with a polynomial with integer coefficients. This is already discussed in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$p(x) = a_0x^n + a_1x^{n-1} +....+a_k$$

At $x=1$ , we have :

$$p(1) = a_0 + a_1+....+a_k = 1$$

Since $a_0 , a_1 , ... ,a_k $ are whole numbers , it follows that exactly one of them is $1$ while the others are $0$ .

If $a_k = 1$ , then $p(x) = 1$ , which has no roots.

If any other term is $1$ , then $p(x) = x^n$ , which has only one root.

Comment: I think by whole number OP means an integer. The term 'whole number' is not very clear.